# Exponential growth function doesn't match example plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I've attempted to replicate the figure 4.4.6 in [this 4.4: The Logistic Equation chapter](https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Community_College_of_Denver/MAT_2420_Calculus_II/04%3A_Introduction_to_Differential_Equations/4.04%3A_The_Logistic_Equation#:%7E:text=1%3A%20Examining%20the%20Carrying%20Capacity%20of%20a%20Deer%20Population,-Let%27s%20consider%20the&text=This%20observation%20corresponds%20to%20a,rate%20is%2023.11%25%20per%20year.)

[image]

However, my plot doesn't match the above example, as the exponential function is pushed over to the right. I double-checked my work, but unsure where I went wrong. Any hints?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-25,25,100)
# P(t)=\dfrac{1,072,764e^{0.2311t}}{0.19196+e^{0.2311t}}
a = [1072764*np.exp(0.2311*x) / (0.19196+np.exp(0.2311*x)) for x in x]
b = 900000*np.exp(0.2311*x) # P(t)=900000e^{(0.2311x)}
plt.axhline(y=1072764, color='r', linestyle='--', label = 'P=1,072,764')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') 
plt.axis([-20, 20, 0, 1400000]) # let's zoom in to see this better

plt.plot(x, a, 'darkblue', label = '$P_0=900,000$') # plotting x, a separately 
plt.plot(x, b, 'turquoise', label = 'Exponential Growth') # plotting x, b separately 
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
# plt.savefig('plots', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Comment: My initial guess is the book is wrong, as its P(0) for the exponential growth is clearly not 900,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure that you are trying to replicate shows an exponential curve that matches value and slope at a point xref (here, -20). Such an exponential curve would have the form
[image]

where Lref and L' are value and slope at the reference point. These latter can be found exactly if you know the formula of your logistic curve L(x), but to a perfectly adequate approximation may be deduced from your already-computed numerical data.

Thus:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-20,20,100)
a = [1072764*np.exp(0.2311*x) / (0.19196+np.exp(0.2311*x)) for x in x]

xref, Lref, Lprime = x[0], a[0], ( a[1] - a[0] ) / ( x[1] - x[0] )
b = Lref * np.exp( (Lprime/Lref) * ( x - xref ) )

plt.axhline(y=1072764, color='r', linestyle='--', label = 'P=1,072,764')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') 
plt.axis([-20, 20, 0, 1400000]) # let's zoom in to see this better

plt.plot(x, a, 'darkblue', label = '$P_0=900,000$') # plotting x, a separately 
plt.plot(x, b, 'turquoise', label = 'Exponential Growth') # plotting x, b separately 
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
# plt.savefig('plots', dpi=300, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

produces output
[image]